# Logic - Given p ⇒ q and m ⇒ p ∨ q, use the Fitch System to prove m ⇒ q.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

It seems to be quite simple but I've yet to solve it. There is this, [Given p ⇒ q and m ⇒ p ∨ q, how would I prove m ⇒ q?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2114381/given-p-%E2%87%92-q-and-m-%E2%87%92-p-%E2%88%A8-q-how-would-i-prove-m-%E2%87%92-q) but it does not satisfy the Fitch System I am using since the 7th and 8th step are not possible as assuming q after line 6 would form another subproof.

Comment: So what rules are available to you?  The proof provided in the post you link to uses fairly standard Fitch rules, so if that doesn't work for you you will really need to explain what rules you have, otherwise we can't help.

Comment: http://imgur.com/qQmIjFT I get to the point where, if I followed the directions in the other post, I would add another assumption on line 7 and then proceed to use an Or Elimination on lines 4,5-6,7-7. For some reason, this is not possible.

Comment: Ah.  It looks like a bug in the machine implementation.  Perhaps you are required to discharge the assumption, with implication introduction to obtain $p\to q$, before proceeding to a second sub-proof?  Then you would use disjunction elimination as $(p\vee q), p\to q, q\to q\vdash q$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp That's an idea!  Alexander, try that ... Also, what program are you using here?  is this available for free online somewhere?

Comment: http://intrologic.stanford.edu/exercises/exercise_04_04.html Knock yourselves out.

Comment: @AlexanderMichalak Yup, just found it myself and just completed the proof. it is exactly what GrahamKemp said: you just need to do a conditional introduction on line 7 to get p=>q, then assume q on line 8, do a conditional introduction to get q =>q, and then do a Or elimination on lines 4,7,9, and conclusde with the conditional inteoduction to get m=>q

Comment: @Bram28 I was able to complete the proof by using the methods discussed previously in the comment tree. http://i.imgur.com/tlxS0WV.png

Comment: @AlexanderMichalak Great! Yeah, that's exactly what I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> as assuming q after line 6 would form another subproof.

It *is* another subproof.   Trivially: assuming $q$, infers $q$.   It is the "first *and* last line of the second subproof." as stated.

---

However, I would use (with reiterations to make it clearer): $$\begin{array}{r|l:l} 1. & p\to q & \text{Premise 1}\\ 2. & m\to (p\vee q) & \text{Premise 2} \\ \hdashline 3. & \quad q & \text{Assumption} \\ \hline 4. & q\to q & 3,3, \text{Implication Introduction} \\ \hdashline 5. & \quad m & \text{Assumption} \\ 6. & \quad m\to (p\vee q) &2,\text{Reiteration} \\ 7. & \quad (p\vee q) & 5,6,\text{Implication Elimination} 
\\ 8. & \quad p\to q & 1, \text{Reiteration}\\ 9. & \quad q\to q & 4,\text{Reiteration} \\ 10. & \quad q & 7,8,9, \text{Disjunction Elimination} \\ \hline \Box & m\to q & 5,10,\text{Implication Introduction}  \end{array}$$